# Opposite of Java next() method

Tags: java

Is there a method that reverses the work of the next() method?

What I'm trying to do is create objects with the data I get from a file and print these objects, but when "Default" is read, the object I created with the constructor should be created and printed.

Text file looks like this:

```
Baha Uysal,1008,Yönetim,CEO
Can Uysal,1511,IT,Web Developer
Estus Candy,4949,Muhasebe,Müşavir
Default 
İlis Kerhan,3535,Pazarlama,Negotiator
```

My code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try {
         fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Can\\Desktop\\girdiQuiz1.txt"));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found !");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while(fileIn.hasNext()) {
        if (fileIn.nextLine() != "Default") {
            Employee worker = new Employee(fileIn.useDelimiter(",|\n").next(), fileIn.useDelimiter(",|\n").nextInt() , fileIn.useDelimiter(",|\n").next(), fileIn.useDelimiter(",|\n").next());
            System.out.println(worker);     
        } 
        else {
            Employee worker = new Employee();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the `if` block is run, it moves to the next data due to the `next()` method and I get an error. I'm new to Java and couldn't fix this. And I also think I'm in trouble with `useDelimiter()`, there are too many.

In short, I need to do the following:

1. Get the data in the file and create objects with a 4-parameter constructor, print these objects.
2. If "Default" comes up, create a default object with a parameterless constructor and print it.

My constructors are ready. The point I'm having trouble with:

1. Creating objects with the data in the file without using lists
2. Not getting an error when "Default" comes.

Comment: No, because some streams can't even be read except in order

Comment: Your input data looks like csv, so I'd recommend you use a [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) instead of manually parsing. CSV can get tricky with quoting.

Comment: @Robert:  That "default" line breaks the CSV convention completely so it'd be *really* risky to try to parse this as a CSV

Comment: @Makoto Yes, good point... I don't know if the csv libraries can be told to just fill a record with `null` if it doesn't have enough fields. OP could also try to fix the format.

Comment: @Robert:  As someone who works with CSV files for a living all I'm going to say is "nooooooo"

Comment: @Robert The method you mentioned and I am too new to comprehend it :)

Comment: Note that `(fileIn.nextLine() != "Default")` is not how you compare Strings. You must use `equals()`.

Comment: @tgdavies I noticed that too late. I switched from Python to Java and very difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

Not for a *stream* of data, no.  Streams are only one direction, and can't be replayed unless they're stored somewhere in memory or on disk for future replaying.

Think of a live TV event, or a radio playing.  You can't go back to see a thing happen in TV or rewind the radio unless you had something specific in memory to keep track of what was played.

The only way around this is to store the contents of the file itself so that you can recall them at some point.  Note that this can be *expensive* to do depending on how big the file is, which is why a lot of conventions recommend using streams to read the data instead.

Since you're reading a file, using [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) would be better.

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Can\\Desktop\\girdiQuiz1.txt")
List<String> fileContents = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
```

From there, you can read individual lines out based on their index position in the list.

```
if(fileContents.get(0).equals("Default")) {
    // business logic
}
```

If you didn't precisely know what line it was, you could maintain a counter instead and re-called lines as necessary.

```
int line = 0;
for(String line : fileContents) {
    line++
    // do stuff with line
}
```

More curiously, with a `List` you *can* get access to [`List#listIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()) which will allow you to go backwards and forwards in the list as necessary.  Just...be careful about how you iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. First of all, I am asked not to use lists for this assignment. Also, I couldn't find how to create an object with a 4-parameter constructor with the data in the list.

Comment: Please take a look at my new edit.